# syntax error, unexpected '!' in laravel 5.1 and class HTML not found

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I am trying to use Html:: class in blade template 5.1, I have tried everything, before I was getting error of `class HTML not found` but when I use `{{ !! HTML::  !!}}` before html, the error is now `FatalErrorException in 75e2b4fe5a49ad69bec8641db04b4b16 line 10:
syntax error, unexpected '!'` guide me please here is code

```
    <li> {{ !! Html:: link_to_route('author',
    $authorname->name, array($authorname->id)) !! }}</li>

    Route: Route::get('authors/{id}', array('as' => 'author', 'uses' => 
    'authors_controller@get_view'));

    Composer.json: "require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
   },

   app.php Providers: Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,             
   app.php Aliases: 
   'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
   'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

and I have used the composer update command or composer require illuminate/html all of these things

Comment: You should read up on http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#displaying-data It needs to be `{{ }}` to work rather than `{{ !! !! }}`

Comment: you mean no spaces before and after !!?

Comment: Sorry, no just remove the !

Comment: you mean from both sides i remove 1

Comment: like {{! Html::  !}}

Comment: No, just have `{{ }}`

Comment: you mean like {{  Html:: }}  but then it says class HTML not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96450/discussion-between-james-and-mohsin).

Answer (score 0):

See Displaying Unescaped Data under [Displaying Data](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#displaying-data) in the Laravel Blade Templating documentation.

Citing the documentation:

By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
Hello, {!! $name !!}.
```

Comment: If you're trying to reference the Html facade, you may need to use \Html if the namespace is not in the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

ahhh, it was painful, well I have discover the solution, there should be single set of curly braces and link_to_route should be linkRoute.

```
{!! Html:: linkRoute  !!}
```